# About audio/ogg, video/ogg and application/ogg Mime Types

Tags: java, html, mime-types, ogg

This is my first question. I hope you can help me.

I´d like to show an audio HTML5 label or a video HTML5 label deppending on a file MimeType.

I´m using this library version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/files/mime-util/mime-util-2.1.3/

```
MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector");
Collection mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(dataFile);

if (mimeTypes.toString().indexOf("audio/ogg") != -1)
{
    <audio>........</audio>
}
else if (mimeTypes.toString().indexOf("video/ogg") != -1)
{
    <video>........</video>
}
```

mimeTypes.toString() always returns to me the MimeType: "application/ogg".

How can I distinguish each case?

Best regards.

Comment: I guess the server is just providing a MimeType based on the file format (Ogg), and not detecting a specific Codec.
You could implement a server filter which provides you more meta-data, or download the first page of the stream to detect the codec manually.